# How to horizontally center chapter name in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\hbox{.}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{5.6cm}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5cm}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{1}{2.5em}{4.6cm}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
     \pagenumbering{roman} 
     \tableofcontents 
     \addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{Chapter No}\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Title}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}
    \onehalfspacing
    \listoffigures
    \addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Figure No}\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Title}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename}
    \onehalfspacing
    \listoftables
    \addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Table No}\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Title}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage 
\chapter{Introduction}
 \section{Problem}
     This is the minimal code
     \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{Abcd}
     \end{figure}
     \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Xyz}
     \end{table}
     \subsection{Only}
 \chapter{Related Works}
 \begin{figure}
    \caption{Bcde}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

**List of figures**

Figure No          Title         Page

```
 1.1          Abcd             iv
 2.1          Bcde             v
```

**List of Tables**
Table No         Title          Page 
1.1              Xyz             iv

I call two commands but calls error:

```
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedlofline{1}{2.5em}{5cm}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedlotline{1}{2.5em}{5cm}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal  compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard In the above code List of figures in table of contents is left aligned and I want to change it to centre or down to the title field in table of contents also chapter no should be down to the chapter no field in table of contents headings other also like that..

Comment: @Bernard  I want increase the horizontal spacing between the chapter no and chapter name in table of contents?..

Comment: what about dottedlines in sections, subsections?

Comment: @touhami  for list of figures I use the following code but it doesn't work  \patchcmd{\@dottedlofline}{\hbox{.}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@figure}{1.5em}{5.6cm}{}{}

Comment: @FASALULFASEEHKA you're welcome. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: @touhami I have problem with the list of figures

Comment: @FASALULFASEEHKA did you see  updated answer?

Comment: @touhami sorry I don't see the update..

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution. We need to

1. remove dots in section like entries
2. redefine commands `\l@chapter`, `\l@section`, ...
3. adjust spacing for starred chapters by `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}`

**Note** in the example below you still have to redefine `\l@subsection` ... if needed.

---

**Update** For list of figure we only need to redefine `\l@figure`
it's similar to `\l@section`

```
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5cm}}
```

Note that **Figure No** is not same length as **Chapter No** so i find it's better to replace 3cm with 3.4cm in

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Figure No}\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Title}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\hbox{.}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{5.6cm}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5cm}}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5cm}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
     \pagenumbering{roman} 
     \tableofcontents 
     \addtocontents{toc}{\textbf{Chapter No}\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Title}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}
    \onehalfspacing
    \listoffigures
    \addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Figure No}\hspace{3.4cm}\textbf{Title}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage 
\chapter{Introduction}
 \section{Problem}
     This is the minimal code
 \chapter{Related Works}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No offense to the code, but the requested result is really ugly and an insult for the reader, at least in my opinion.